# android-ndk caused error at building using cygwin

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, cygwin

I am follow this [link](https://code.commotionwireless.net/projects/commotion/wiki/Commotion_Android_buildinstalltesting) to build their project, I have already prepared the environment(android sdk, android ndk, cygwin) on XP PC.

when I follow their steps, I didn't understand what they meant by this step

```
It may be helpful to explicitly identify the SDK's location in the shell variables   SDK_BASE & NDK_BASE, & to call out which version of each you wish to build with. For   instance, add something like this to ~/.bashrc:

export SDK_BASE=~/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk
export NDK_BASE=~/android/android-ndk-r8d
export SDK_PLATFORM_LEVEL=16
export NDK_PLATFORM_LEVEL=9s
```

**So I skip this step!!**

when I continued their steps I face problem when I need to make the C files by type this command

```
make -C external/
```

this caused error in try to build these files, and this appeared :
[image]

So how can I solve this problem ? and have successful build ?

Answer (score 0):

It can't find your ndk installation! Those steps you skipped are important. For now, just type them into the command line before you build.

The problem with this is you'll lose these definitions when you close the terminal. The solution to *this* problem is to add those lines to your `~/.bashrc` file:

Assuming it doesn't exist, you can create it on the command line with: `touch ~/.bashrc`

Then open this hidden file in your favourite text editor and add the export statements.